# Code igniter Form Validation with All Fields Posted as an Array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, post, validation

I'm facing a problem regarding general form validation in codeigniter. In my case, the fields are posted in array `$m_data = json_decode($this->input->post('data'));` and needs to be validated before sending them to the model. see this example

```
        $m_data = json_decode($this->input->post('data'));          
        $validation_rules = array(
             $m_data['title']   => 'trim|xss_clean|required|max_length[50]',
             $m_data['code']    => 'trim|xss_clean|required|max_length[50]'
        );
        foreach ($validation_rules as $key => $value){
            $this->form_validation->set_rules($key,$key,$value);
        }


        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            foreach ($validation_rules as $key => $value){          
                $m_data[$key] = $this->form_validation->set_value($key);
            }
            // do insertion
        }
```

the problem here that form validation will take each field separately as posted data using the 'key' of value posted and run the rules over it. I tried to create **custom validation** that receive an array of fields as input but I had no clue how to do  this.

can you help me figuring a way to validate the array content using CI form validation, any input is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, I found the answer to this that really works, but I think it's just temporary answer so don't depend on it, but it works.

```
        $validation_rules = $this->config->item('class');
        foreach ($validation_rules as $row){
            $_POST[$row['field']] = $m_data->$row['field'];         
        }
```

what I did here is to set the `$_POST['name_of_fields_in_the_array'`] by the value posted from the view which is `$m_data`, and that made the validation works very well

Answer (score 4):

You can use arrays as field names with CI form validation.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#arraysasfields

What you would need to do is something like this.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('data[]', 'Data', 'trim|xss_clean|required|max_length[50]');

if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
// DO INSERT
}
else
{
// LOAD VIEWS
}
```

I'm pretty sure the rules are applied recursively through your data, but I'd do some tests to make sure. I tried it with different field types (see HTML below) and it was working for the required rule at least. (This is just quick HTML, I'd use the CI form helper).

```
<input type="radio" value="Test data" name="data[]" />
<input type="radio" value=" More data " name="data[]" />
<input type="radio" value="3" name="data[]" />
<input type="input" value="" name="data[]" />
```

This will only work if all your rules are the same for every field.

Comment: notice that fields array will be posted using ajax ($.Post), response in my case will be only true or false. so there is no need for the view call.

Comment: that's didn't work or me sorry, what I need is a way to replace the way form_validation receive input from $_POST['title'] to the the actual data it self